# Call function to pass parameter in the DataTables reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, datatables

I use the JQuery DataTables plugin and I initialize it with ajax parameter.

I'll need to calcolate new parameter when I reload data but not run if I pass parameter in the function.
I call the ajax.reload from a "Reload" button.
Why I can not use function with parameter?

```
// Run correctly
function loadData(){alert("called");}
tab=$("#tabID").DataTable({ajax:{url:"a.php",data:loadData}}); //  The "loadData" is called
...
$("#tabID").DataTable().ajax.reload(); //  The "loadData" is called again
```

---

```
// Problem
function loadData(A){alert("called with "+A);}
tab=$("#tabID").DataTable({ajax:{url:"a.php",data:loadData("text")}}); //  The "loadData" is called
...
$("#tabID").DataTable().ajax.reload(); // The "loadData" is NOT called... why?
```

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
$("#tabID").DataTable({
   ajax: {
      url: "a.php",
      data: function(data, settings){
         return loadData("text");
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have modify the script with "return" before loadData("text");

Answer (score 1):

```
// Problem
function loadData(A){alert("called with "+A);}
tab=$("#tabID").DataTable({ajax:{url:"a.php",data:loadData("text")}}); //  The "loadData" is called
...
$("#tabID").DataTable().ajax.reload(); // The "loadData" is NOT called... why?
```

It is just because in second case you pass to `data:` property result of loadData() not the function, you can bind your parameter like

```
tab=$("#tabID").DataTable({ajax:{url:"a.php",data:loadData.bind(null, "text")}});
```

read more about [bind](https://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.5)

if your browser not implemented bind, you can use handmade bind, or shim,

this code explains what bind make for you in this case

```
function bindArgs() { // this shim will not use 1st parameter, so should called as (bindArgs(callback, arguments);
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var callback = args.shift();
    return function() { //return new function
           callback.apply(null, args); // run real callback
    }
}
function run() {console.log(arguments)}
setTimeout(bindArgs(run, 1,2,3), 1000)
```